# Correctly adding a signal handler to Asyncio code

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to modify the graceful shutdown example from [RogueLynn](https://www.roguelynn.com/words/asyncio-graceful-shutdowns/) to cancel running processes that were spawned by the tasks.

Below is a minimal example to demonstrate the issue I'm facing. With this example, I get a warning message that the callback function isn't awaited and when I do try to terminate the script, the asyncio.gather call doesn't seem to complete. Any idea how to resolve this such that the shutdown callback executes completely?

```
import asyncio
import functools
import signal

async def run_process(time):
    try:
        print(f"Starting to sleep for {time} seconds")
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        print(f"Completed sleep of {time} seconds")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Received cancellation terminating process")
        raise

async def main():

    tasks = [run_process(10), run_process(5), run_process(2)]
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        try:
            await future
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Caught exception: {e}")

async def shutdown(signal, loop):
    # Cancel running tasks on keyboard interrupt
    print(f"Running shutdown")
    tasks = [t for t in asyncio.all_tasks() if t is not asyncio.current_task()]
    [task.cancel() for task in tasks]

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    print("Finished waiting for cancelled tasks")
    loop.stop()


try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    signals = (signal.SIGINT,)
    for sig in signals:
        loop.add_signal_handler(sig, functools.partial(asyncio.create_task, shutdown(sig, loop)))

    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Output when run to completion:

```
Starting to sleep for 2 seconds
Starting to sleep for 10 seconds
Starting to sleep for 5 seconds
Completed sleep of 2 seconds
Completed sleep of 5 seconds
Completed sleep of 10 seconds
/home/git/envs/lib/python3.8/asyncio/unix_events.py:140: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'shutdown' was never awaited
  del self._signal_handlers[sig]
```

And output when script is interrupted:

```
Starting to sleep for 2 seconds
Starting to sleep for 10 seconds
Starting to sleep for 5 seconds
Completed sleep of 2 seconds
^CRunning shutdown
Received cancellation terminating process
Received cancellation terminating process
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<shutdown() running at ./test.py:54> wait_for=<_GatheringFuture finished result=[CancelledError(), CancelledError(), CancelledError()]>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 65, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/home/git/envs/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CancelledError` you see results from your `as_completed` for loop.
If you just want to fix it, you could add an exception handling for it, e.g.

```
[...]
        try:
            await future
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Caught exception: {e}")
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("task was cancelled") 
[...]
```

Note that, you will find a warning telling you that `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` for your shutdown task, which you could just ignore. I guess it is because you stop the loop within a task.

Still, I would like to point at the difference between co-routines, tasks, and futures, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html.
What you call `tasks` and `future` are co-routines.

For the type of problem that you are trying to solve, I would advise to have a look at Asynchronous Context Managers. Graceful shutdown sounds to me like you want to close some database connections or dump some process variables... Here, you could have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager
However, if things become more complex, you may want to write such a signal handler which adds its own task to the loop. In this case, I would advise to create the relevant tasks explicitly with `asyncio.create_task(coro, name="my-task-name")` so you can select exactly the tasks you want to cancel  first by name, e.g.

```
tasks = [
    task for task in asyncio.all_tasks() 
    if task.get_name().startswith("my-task")
]
```

Otherwise, you may accidentally cancel a cleanup-task.